# Selenium not working properly with headless mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to extract the text of the first listing from the url using Selenium and headless browser. The code works fine if it's not in headless mode, but not returning anything and not working fine in headless mode. Here's the code.

```
import requests  
import time
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions 
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2'  

options = FirefoxOptions()  
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')  
options.add_argument("--headless")  
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')  
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)  
start_url = "https://ammoseek.com/ammo/300aac-blackout?pl=no&co=new&ca=brass" #works with US IP
driver.get(start_url)  
time.sleep(5)  
text = driver.find_element_by_class_name('results-card').text  
print (text)
```

Comment: There is DDoS protection which blocks page from opening

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your code without specifying `user-agent`.

You may also try to use Google Chrome webdriver instead.